# Finding the range of a function given the domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> The function $f$ is defined by $f : x \rightarrow 10 - (x-3)^2$
> for $2\leq x\leq 7$. Find the range of $f$

I tried substituting the minimum and maximum $x$ values to find the range but my answer was incorrect. I think it has something to do with understanding this notation $f : x \rightarrow$ but I don't understand how it's different from solving $f(x)$.

Comment: The notation $f: x \rightarrow 10-(x-3)^2$ is the same as saying $f(x) = 10-(x-3)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ can take any value from $2$ to $7$, $x-3$ can take any value from $-1$ to $4$, and therefore $-(x-3)^2$ can take any value from $0$ to $-16$. Therefore, the range of your function is $[-6,10]$, since $10+0=10$ and $10-16=-6$.

Answer (score 1):

- For any real $x$, the value of  $x^2$ never becomes negative. It means that the  minimum value of $x^2$ is $0$ when $x=0$.
- For any real $x$, the value of  $-x^2$ never becomes positive. It means that the  maximum value of $-x^2$ is $0$ when $x=0$.
- Generalizing the above facts. For any real $x$, the maximum value of $-(x-p)^2+q$ is $q$ when $x=p$.

Now proceed to your problem.

- $f(x)=10-(x-3)^2$ has maximum value of $10$ when $x=3$.
- As the critical point $(3,10)$ is sandwiched by the given domain $2\le x\le7$, we have to check values of $f(x)$ at the boundary of the given domain.
  \begin{align}
       f(2)&=9\\
       f(7)&=-6
     \end{align}
  The minimum of $f(x)$ in $2\le x\le7$ is $-6$.
- Thus the range of $f(x)$ in $2\le x\le7$ is $[-6,10]$.

Comment: Do we have to find the turning point (max) of every quadratic function that we want to find the maximum value of? why cant we just use the maximum and minimum value of x given in the domain to find the range by substituiting?

Comment: @Ahmed:  For $a\le x \le b$, it is NOT guaranteed that either $f(a)\le f(x) \le f(b)$ or $f(b)\le f(x) \le f(a)$ is true. Why? Because you don't know the behavior of $f(x)$ in the given interval. If $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing, $f(a)\le f(x) \le f(b)$ is true. If $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, $f(b)\le f(x) \le f(a)$ is true. Otherwise  you cannot make any conclusion. That is why you need to know the turning point.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $f(x)=10 - (x-3)^2,\space2\le x \le 7,\quad$ then a spreadsheet using $0.1$ increments of $\space x \space $ shows that
$\space -6 \le f(x) \le 10.\space$

The logic of José Carlos Santos is also quit sound.

Answer (score 0):

2$\le x \le 7$ if and only if
2-3$\le x-3 \le 7-3$ iff
-1$\le  x-3 \le 4$ if
0$\le (x-3)^2 \le 16$ iff
0$\ge -(x-3)^2 \ge -16 $ iff
10$\ge 10-(x-3)^2 \ge 10-16 $ iff
10$\ge f(x) \ge -6 $ and hence the range of f is [-6 10].